# How to do parallel execution of function calls using Futures in scala

Tags: multithreading, scala, apache-spark, parallel-processing, future

I want to call a `func()` with different parameters and calling to this function should happen in parallel.

```
for(i <- 0 to count) {
    Future {
        for(j <- 0 to n_count) {
            Future {
                func(a,b, c(i), d(j))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Is it the right way?**

Also my function is not returning anything. So how to know execution is running in parallel or how many threads has been created. Please provide full code for such scenario in Scala.

Comment: why not use parallelize instead of future?

Comment: This question is too vague with little information. Please post a [MCVE] of your problem. Specifically, what are `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`? What are their types and what values do they hold? What are you trying to do with this for comprehension?

Comment: @SMA how to do that

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I want to run func(a,b,c[1],d[1]) func(a,b,c[1],d[2]) func(a,b,c[2],d[1]) func(a,b,c[2],d[2]) .....so on in parallel. Arguments are just string and list of strings. I just want this above calling(say 4 func) to execute in parallel.

Comment: @Jasper-M I didn't ask for syntax errors in my code. I asked about parallelism.

Comment: Well when you ask for people to give you the full code for your problem it helps if you get the basic concepts right.

Comment: @Jasper-M So can you suggest code for parallely executing above func()

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple, scala gives you `Future.sequence` and `Future.traverse` for this reason

They both roughly work the same way, by converting any collection of the kind `M[Future[T]]` to a collection of `Future[M[T]]`, but they are used differently.

```
val actions = List(Future(5), Future(6), Future(7))
val executed = Future.sequence(actions) map (l => println(l.mkString()) // 5, 6 ,7
```

Now `Future.traverse` is semantically different because you feed it an `M[A]`, or a collection of elements, and then a function that converts those elements to a future. For instance:

```
val userIds = List(1, 2, 3, 4 , 5)
// let's pretend this calls an SQL DB
def userById(id: Int): Future[Option[User]]
Future.traverse(userIds)(id => userById(id))
```

In terms of execution semantics, both constructs execute all futures in parallel and fail if any of the futures fail. There's no guarantee the futures are executed in order.

Off topic, but fortunately it's pretty easy to write a "one at a time logic 
yourself. This works by moving the function that produces the `Future` from an element "inside" the for block. Futures in Scala are always created in an already started state, which makes them harder to reason about.

```
def sequencedTraverse[
    A,
    B,
    M[X] <: TraversableOnce[X]
  ](in: M[A])(fn: A => Future[B])(implicit
    executor: ExecutionContextExecutor,
    cbf: CanBuildFrom[M[A], B, M[B]]
  ): Future[M[B]] = {
    in.foldLeft(Future.successful(cbf(in))) { (fr, a) =>
      for (r <- fr; b <- fn(a)) yield r += b
    }.map(_.result())
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on the excellent answer of @flavian:

```
scala> val a = "a"
a: String = a

scala> val b = "b"
b: String = b

scala> val c = List("x","y","z")
c: List[String] = List(x, y, z)

scala> val d = List("u","v","w")
d: List[String] = List(u, v, w)

scala> def func(a: String, b: String, c: String, d: String) = a + b + c + d
func: (a: String, b: String, c: String, d: String)String

scala> val futures = for{i <- c; j <- d} yield Future(func(a,b,i,j))
futures: List[scala.concurrent.Future[String]] = List(Future(Success(abxu)), Future(Success(abxv)), Future(Success(abxw)), Future(Success(abyu)), Future(Success(abyv)), Future(Success(abyw)), Future(Success(abzu)), Future(Success(abzv)), Future(Success(abzw)))

scala> Future.sequence(futures)
res0: scala.concurrent.Future[List[String]] = Future(<not completed>)

scala> res0
res1: scala.concurrent.Future[List[String]] = Future(Success(List(abxu, abxv, abxw, abyu, abyv, abyw, abzu, abzv, abzw)))
```